# Meaning of “See who by grace see may”

Tags: meaning, middle-english

I am reading an English text in an old book and it reads:

> See who by grace see may, for the feeling of this is endless bliss, and the contrary is endless pain.

This is the original text:

> See, who bi grace see may, for the felyng of this is eendles blisse; and the contrary is eendles pyne

What does this mean "See who by grace see may"?

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? How much do you understand?

Comment: @CJDennis I do not get the "see who by grace see may". I'm confused about the structure of this sentence.

Comment: The text appears to come from _The Cloud of Unknowing_, translated by Evelyn Underhill, (1922). https://sacred-texts.com/chr/cou/cou09.htm The quote needs more context, but the paragraph is quite long. If you can add more text for context without quoting the whole paragraph, that would be helpful. I might edit your question myself if I can work out how to make it better.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cloud_of_Unknowing The text was originally written in Middle English, not Old English. I don't know how much of the original language survives in Evelyn Underhill's work, so I don't know whether we should consider this genuine Middle English or confusing Modern English. It is also written from a Christian viewpoint, so that will most likely be relevant to any answer.

Comment: @CJDennis I added the original text in the main question (https://d.lib.rochester.edu/teams/text/gallacher-cloud-of-unknowing). It definitely is a Christian text. I thought this particular phrase is expressing a prayer or a wish; meaning that "whoever agrees with me will be in eternal bliss..." But I am not sure about the exact meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly, but it seems to me to mean:

> See, who by grace **may see**

I've swapped the order of the last two words. In other words:

> See, [those of you] who by [the] grace [of God] may see

This might not be correct, but without being familiar with Middle English, this is how I would understand it.

Comment: I agree. This is what I guessed and it matches the context of this book. Thanks

Comment: You should wait for more answers (a couple of days) before marking an answer correct, unless it's obviously right. I have admitted in the answer that I'm guessing at best. Someone else could come up with a better answer that proves my answer wrong.